# Dynamic variable from client-side to server-side back to client-side. JSP

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsp, dom

In the code below how can I get the `dVariable` show into my JSPF with a click, and if I submit it to the server, how do I return that value to the client-side JSPF page?

I've been able to accomplish this by creating `div` tags CSS styled as `display:none`  inside a loop, and changing them to `display:block`, when clicked. But that is a very static solution.

I don't want to have a lot of hidden divs and show the one of interest. I'm looking for a more refined solution, such as a single div that's always visible and the contents are updated with the variable in realtime.

**details.jspf:**

```
<%= dVariable %> // From the specific table button, without multiple div's.
```

**JavaScript and HTML:**

```
function loadJSPF(){
    document.getElementById("JSPF").style.display("block"); 
}

<table>
    <tr>
        <% for (int x : amount){ %> 
            <td>Info1</td>
            <td>Info2</td>
            <td>Info3</td>
            <td><button onclick="LoadJSPF()">dVariable</td>
        <% } %>
    <tr>
<table>     

<div id="jspf" name="jspf">
    <@ include file="/sys/ins/001/incl/details.jspf" %>
</div>
```

Comment: With AJAX, you make a server-side request of a certain type from JavaScript and declare a callback handler. It submits the content to the server with HTTP, and when the response is received from the server, your callback handler (in JavaScript) updates whatever it needs to in the DOM. Again - how that works with JSP, that glue, is what I don't have any information about.

Comment: @clearlight Thank you thank you! Definitely pointed me in the right direction (:! That makes sense, yes Ajax is usable here. Going to search in that direction, got a clearer picture in my head.